# NGINX redirect non-existent domains

Tags: nginx, centos, https

Lets say I have the following domain:

`example.com`

with these subdomains:

`test.example.com`

`prod.example.com`

All only accessable through HTTPS. When someone enters `https://test2.example.com` or any other non-existent subdomain, they get served the standard NGINX `index.html` file. Instead, I want them to be redirected back to `https://example.com`.

This is what my server block `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` looks like:

```
    server {
        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
        server_name  example;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;


        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        return  301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

I was hoping the line `return  301 https://example.com$request_uri;` would solve this problem, but it isn't working. Chrome displays following error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

What is working, is the URI int the address bar changes from `test2.example.com` to `example.com`. Im just having an issue with too many redirects. Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You currently have one server block which is also the default server block.

You should separate that into two blocks. One block handles the *named* domains and another handles all of the non-existent domains:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

server {
    listen  443 ssl default_server;
    listen  [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    return  301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen  443 ssl http2;
    listen  [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name  example.com test.example.com prod.example.com;

    root    /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index   index.html

    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Many of the `ssl_xxx` directives can be placed above the `server` blocks (within the surrounding `http` block) so that they are inherited by both - or you can copy them into each server block (your choice).

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) for more.

Comment: You should specify that the visitor **will get a security warning** if the certificate do not cover the domain asked. (even if it's a wildcard certificate it cover only one sublevel)

Answer (score 0):

In Nginx your server_name could be *.example.com (but not *.example.*), so all hostnames test.example.com, test2.example.com, prod.example.com can be served by one website if you want.
If you apply for a wildcard DNS SSL certificate, then you can use https on all websites under example.com.

You can segregate the sites, and only use one certificate, by creating one or more server blocks in nginx.