# Redirect my https://123.456.567.789 to https://example.com || Nginx

Tags: nginx, 301-redirect

I want to create redirection rule for my site,

i want to redirect my site from ip to domain, but its working fine in non-https , but when i type https://id-address it opens as it is, no redirection.

here is my conf file.

```
    # HTTP server

    server {
        listen       80;
       server_name  localhost;

       #include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

      include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";


}
    # HTTPS server

    server {
       listen       443 ssl;
       server_name  example.com;

    ssl_certificate example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key example.com.key;

       ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
       ssl_session_timeout  5m;

       ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

       #include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

       include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";

    }

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf";



# Status
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name local-stackdriver-agent.stackdriver.com;
    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      access_log   off;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
    }
    location / {
      root /dev/null;
    }
}

server {
    server_name 123.456.789.100  www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of `server` blocks, but only one processing requests for `https`. You could set up a catch-all server block, for an example see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/825786/nginx-redirect-non-existent-domains/825796#825796).

Comment: hello, all i want is redirect from "https://www.example.com" , "https://123.456.789.457" to "https://example.com"

Comment: To redirect a web browser has to connect to the web server. To connect https there needs to be a certificate for that domain or IP, otherwise instead of a redirect the browser will just show a security warning or error. Certificates are almost never issued for IPs. You need to reconsider what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

While it's theoretically possible, you can't easily in practice create a https certificate for an IP address. If you really, really need to do this you'll find a certificate authority who will do this for you, but I suspect in most cases you're best off finding another solution or looking at your problem in a different way.

Comment: Just because someone doesn't like my answer that doesn't mean it's incorrect.